# Create multi ring buffer in QGIS that includes 0 distance polygon as well

Tags: qgis, buffer, ring, multi

I am trying to take a polygons shapefile with hundreds of polygons and draw multi ring buffers around the borders of each polygon, with 25 rings at distance intervals of 30 meters. Ok fine. This is straightforward using the following settings within the Multi Ring Buffer QGIS plugin:
[image]

This successfully produces a multi ring buffer layer where the buffers overlap and are not dissolved.

I then go to this new buffered layer's attribute table and see a new row produced for each buffer distance, starting with the 30 meter buffer, and then going out in increasing increments of 30 meters. What I want to do next is use zonal statistics to take the average value of an underlying raster layer within each of these 30-meter buffer rings (or "doughnuts" as it is sometimes called). However, while doing this is straightforward, the problem is that I also want to calculate zonal statistics on the non-buffered polygons themselves (e.g. 0 meters distance), and find the average value of the underlying raster for the original polygon itself. And so rather than starting the rows at 30. I want a preceding row of 0 meters, so this column would show "mrb_dist: 0, 30, 60, 90, 120,..." (mrb = multi ring buffer), and thus adding that new 0-distance row for each polygon.

Is there a way to include the original non-buffered polygon itself in this newly created multi ring buffer layer within this Multi Ring Buffer QGIS tool?

Comment: Just copy the initial (unbuffered) polygons and paste it on the layer with the buffered polygons. Or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: or just merge your original layer with the multi-buffered-layer

Comment: have you tried specifying the distances, starting with 0?

Comment: @Babel I think you understand correctly, but I am just unsure as to whether this would be spatial join or an intersection.

Comment: @PieterB I think merging would be good. Would this be referred to as an intersection or a spatial join in QGIS though? I am a bit unsure as to which would be more suitable here.

Comment: @JGH I did not know I could do that. I see the `Distances` option I can enter a list of numbers into, but I was not sure if that was what I should be using, since I thought I should enter 25 in the `Rings` option and 30 in the `Buffer Distance` option, so that the tool automatically creates each ring. Using you suggestion, would that just mean entering the same thing manually in the `Distances` option, including 0, and so entering '0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, ... 720, 750'?

Comment: Yes, but try it with just a few rings first :-)   (PS: and use a spreadsheet to generate the numbers + comas, then a text editor to replace the line breaks with nothing to remove them)